# How should I use the fbox command correctly to avoid producing a Bad Box message?

Tags: boxes, unit-of-measure

I come from this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25905/152550) and the response that is given is very good.

I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\vspace{5mm}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{30em}
    \underline{\textbf{NOTACI\'ON}}: Dada \(f:D\subseteq \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R\) con \(y=f(x)\) para denotar la funci\'on derivada se puede encontrar en la bibliograf\'ia disponible de la materia las siguientes notaciones: \[\begin{array}{cccc}f'(x), & D_xf, & \dfrac{df}{dx}, & \dfrac{dy}{dx}\end{array}.\]  Todas ellas son equivalentes y que utilizaremos indistintamente en lo sucesivo.
\end{minipage}}
\vspace{5mm}

\end{document}
```

where I modify the `fbox` value (which is `30em`) manually. But that is not the correct width of box (according to the margins of the document). So I change `30em`for `\textwidth` value, and when I compile it says that there is an Bad Box (I clarify that approximately from `31em` onwards the Bad Box message appears). How can I avoid that message?

[image: Using a measure versus not using it]

**Should I manually enter the value or is there some *(easy)* way to not have to worry about every box in my document?**

Thanks!

Comment: There is a little bit white space (`fboxsep`) on all sides of the box to the text. This space is added to the linewidth, hence the whole box needs more space and creates a warning.

Comment: What you really should do: Create semantic markup, instead of doing the layout each and every time.

Comment: To resolve you immediate issue instead of `\textwidth` use `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-2\fboxsep}` and include `\usepackage{calc}`. Also, you need a `\noindent` _before_ the `\fbox{}`. But, yes defintly do as @Johannes_B recommends and define a custom environment instead of tweaking every use of this. I'd recomment looking into `tcolorbox` (there are numerous examples on this site).  Also, adding the `showframe` package will clearly show you what is happening with you add the `\noindent` and the `-2\fboxsep`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for your explanation! I am a beginner with LaTeX, so I have to learn a lot about programming (even if I'm studying a career in Computer Science haha).

Comment: @PeterGrill I'm going to take your recommendation about that alternative that you propose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a "changed" fbox called `\myfbox`  and expecting as arguments an optional for width and a mandatory (its content)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newlength{\mywidth}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myfbox[2][\linewidth]{%
\xdef\mysep{\dimexpr 1\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax\relax}%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{\mysep}%
\setlength{\mywidth}{\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}%
\noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}[inner sep=0]{\mywidth}#2\end{minipage}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Large

\myfbox[\linewidth]{
\underline{\textbf{NOTACI\'ON}}: Dada \(f:D\subseteq \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R\) con \(y=f(x)\) para denotar la funci\'on derivada se puede encontrar en la bibliograf\'ia disponible de la materia las siguientes notaciones: \[\begin{array}{cccc}f'(x), & D_xf, & \dfrac{df}{dx}, & \dfrac{dy}{dx}\end{array}.\]  Todas ellas son equivalentes y que utilizaremos indistintamente en lo sucesivo.}


Dada \(f:D\subseteq \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R\) con \(y\) para denotar la funci\'on derivada se puede encontrar en la bibliograf\'ia disponible de la materia las siguientes notaciones:

\normalsize

\myfbox[\textwidth]{\underline{\textbf{NOTACI\'ON}}: Dada \(f:D\subseteq \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R\) con \(y=f(x)\) para denotar la funci\'on derivada se puede encontrar en la bibliograf\'ia disponible de la materia las siguientes notaciones: \[\begin{array}{cccc}f'(x), & D_xf, & \dfrac{df}{dx}, & \dfrac{dy}{dx}\end{array}.\]  Todas ellas son equivalentes y que utilizaremos indistintamente en lo sucesivo.}

\scriptsize

\begin{center}
\myfbox[0.7\textwidth]{\underline{\textbf{NOTACI\'ON}}: Dada \(f:D\subseteq \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R\) con \(y=f(x)\) para denotar la funci\'on derivada se puede encontrar en la bibliograf\'ia disponible de la materia las siguientes notaciones: \[\begin{array}{cccc}f'(x), & D_xf, & \dfrac{df}{dx}, & \dfrac{dy}{dx}\end{array}.\]  Todas ellas son equivalentes y que utilizaremos indistintamente en lo sucesivo.}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

PS: Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102739/120578 from @GonzaloMedina

PS2: May be is not good idea to include the `\noindent` command in my definition of the box (You can remove it from there and use it whenever needed)

Comment: Many thanks! It is fine with `\noident` command `:)`. The only thing I have to add was the vertical spacing up and down the custom box you created so that the text is not so close to it.
I should learn all the commands that you use in your code. What draws my attention is the meaning of the `\relax` command and all that ... I'm passionate about LaTex!