# Put a rounded corner box in a beamer template

Tags: beamer, equations, box

I am trying to put a rounded corners box that contains an equation. I keep having an error: 'Missing $ inserted' and I don't understand why?

Could someone help me to figure it out please?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation*}
    \ovalbox{\nabla \zeta_0 = -\frac{\delta r}{h^{*}}  \ \text{avec :}\ \frac{1}{h^{*}} = \frac{1}{\alpha h_p} - \frac{1}{H}}
    \end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- the argument of `\ovalbox` must be in math mode

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \ovalbox{$\nabla \zeta_0 = -\frac{\delta r}{h^{*}}  \ \text{avec :}\ \frac{1}{h^{*}} = \frac{1}{\alpha h_p} - \frac{1}{H}$}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it works ! Could I ask you too if it's possible to impose same height of ovalboxes for 2 different boxes side to side ? Like in this code if I add another one :                                                                                                          `\begin{equation*}
    \ovalbox{$\nabla \zeta_0 = -\frac{\delta r}{h^{*}}  \ \text{avec :}\ \frac{1}{h^{*}} = \frac{1}{\alpha h_p} - \frac{1}{H}$}
    \
    \ovalbox{$\alpha = 1 - \frac{n}{n'} \ \text{et :} \ h_p = h_0$}
    \end{equation*}`

Comment: Have a look at [How to specify height and width of \fbox{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102737/123129).

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `hf-tikz` package instead. This has some nice additional features, like overlay awareness, control over height and size...

Off-topic: you don't need to load `amsmath`, beamer loads it automatically.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[beamer,customcolors,nofill]{hf-tikz}
\hfsetbordercolor{black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation*}
    \tikzmarkin<1->{a}(0.1,-0.4)(-0.1,0.6) 
    \nabla \zeta_0 = -\frac{\delta r}{h^{*}}  \quad \text{avec :}\quad \frac{1}{h^{*}} = \frac{1}{\alpha h_p} - \frac{1}{H} 
    \tikzmarkend{a}
    \end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or one could use the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
  every box/.style={
    highlight math style={
      colback=bg,
      colframe=black
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation*}
    \tcbhighmath{
    \nabla \zeta_0 = -\frac{\delta r}{h^{*}}  \quad \text{avec :}\quad \frac{1}{h^{*}} = \frac{1}{\alpha h_p} - \frac{1}{H} 
    }
    \end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]